# from xml.dom import DOMImplementation, DocumentType

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get a Python script working, that is using xml.dom (not xml.dom.minidom).

I'm working on a new install of Python 2.7 for Windows, and xml.dom doesn't have a DOMImplementation or a DocumentType.

Is there some additional module I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bother everybody.

On further examination, it turns out that the code I was trying to get working simply doesn't work. In essence, it was an attempt to write a SOAP client using Python's xml.dom and httplib modules - and it was simply done wrong.

I'm scrapping his code, and writing a proper SOAP client.

Answer (score 0):

`xml.dom` only provides DOM interfaces, it is *not* a DOM implementation.

Only `xml.dom.minidom` provides an implementation; `xml.dom.pulldom` provides a on-demand tree builder.

Note that the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) offers a far more Pythonic API to process XML documents; unless you are married to the DOM API, you'll find the ElementTree API to be easier to use for most use cases.

Comment: I'm not trying to write a script that manipulates DOM, I'm trying to get what is supposed to be an already-working script to work. From what I can see, the guy who wrote it had no idea what he was doing.

Comment: @JeffDege: If all the script does is import `xml.dom` then the script could perhaps have worked if a 3rd-party library registered a DOM implementation using [`xml.dom.registerDOMImplementation`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.registerDOMImplementation). I don't personally know of any libraries that do, but that doesn't mean there were none, the methods are only really there to meet DOM implementation expectations.

Comment: Comments on the script indicate that he wrote it using Python 2.4 and the PyXML libraries for Python 2.4. And that when he tried to build it using Python 2.5, it didn't work, so he stuck to 2.4. In other words, the script is pretty much useless.

Comment: Right; PyXML is very much obsolete now; you could try to port the script to `minidom` or move to using ElementTree instead. Personally, I'd go with the latter.

Comment: In essence the `xml.dom` namespace in the Python stdlib is a stripped-down version of the PyXML project, and it used the same namespace. But only the `minidom` implementation was retained.

Comment: Correction; I see now that PyXML took the Python 2.0 `xml.dom` package as a starting point.